# Kruskal Wallis test or Friedman for multiple preselected unmatched pairs

Tags: multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

I am unsure whether I should use Kruskal Wallis test or Friedman's test in the following case, where I am required to use a non-parametric test while compensating for multiple comparison with a post hoc test.

I would like to compare the median of different parameters sampled from two distinct study groups (independent groups: Group 0 = 10 subjects, Group 1 = 20 subjects) while compensating for multiple comparison.

I would like to compare mean ranks for a preselected pairs of columns (e.g. using Dunn's test):

I have three different parameters, which I respectively measure in my groups: Paramx, Paramy, and Paramz

Paramx in Group 1 vs Paramx in Group 0

Paramy in Group 1 vs Paramy in Group 0

Paramz in Group 1 vs Paramz in Group 0

I am having an issue with the assumption of the Kruskal-Wallis test that observations in one group should be independent of observations in all other groups. While I compare mean ranks for preselected independent pairs, the Kruskal Wallis test compares all groups (6 groups in total, 3x Group 0, 3x Group 1, which are not independent in a conservative sense as the parameters were sampled from those two respective groups).

However, for Friedmann's test I would expect a study design with matched pairs and repeated-measures, which isn't the case here.

Is Kruskal Wallis test the correct test here?

Comment: You are not comparing numerically between x, y, and z characteristics, are you? So this is not related-samples comparison. You are doing a comparison between two groups for each characteristic separately.

Comment: I am doing comparisons between two group medians without direct-matching/pairing between the subjects. Yes, I am not comparing numerically.

Comment: Kruskal Wallis is not generally a test of medians. Comparing mean ranks isn't necassarily the same as comparing median. This was many times discussed on this site. Read posts for Kruskal-Wallis tag.

Comment: Regardless of comparing mean ranks, "dominance" or medians, I need a statistical test, which can analyze whether there is a statistical difference between both groups.

Comment: So you need a repeated-measures ANOVA?

Comment: no, it needs to be non-parametric.